# How do i put new line after iterating certain section of text file using batch script

Tags: javascript, batch-file, batch-processing

Please help me with this thanks,
This is my text file

```
2000,license(s) used by Mani@EXE-138 [180.16.10.168] 
21000,license(s) used by Mani@TEST-138 [180.16.10.168] 
21000,license(s) used by Mani@TEST-138 [180.16.10.168] 
21000,license(s) used by Mani@TEST-138 [180.16.10.168] 
2000,license(s) used by Benjamin@DEMO-35 [180.16.10.55] 
21000,license(s) used by Benjamin@DEMO-35 [180.16.10.55] 
21000,license(s) used by Benjamin@DEMO-35 [180.16.10.55] 
21000,license(s) used by Benjamin@DEMO-35 [180.16.10.55] 
21000,license(s) used by STARHPC@TEST-42 [180.16.10.72] 
21000,license(s) used by STARHPC@TEST-42 [180.16.10.72] 
21000,license(s) used by STARHPC@TEST-42 [180.16.10.72] 
1,license(s) used by starhpc@TEST-80 [180.16.10.90] 
21000,license(s) used by starhpc@TEST-80 [180.16.10.90] 
21000,license(s) used by starhpc@TEST-80 [180.16.10.90] 
21000,license(s) used by starhpc@TEST-80 [180.16.10.90] 
21000,license(s) used by starhpc@TEST-80 [180.16.10.90] 
21000,license(s) used by starhpc@TEST-80 [180.16.10.90] 
21000,license(s) used by JITHIN THOMAS@TEST-36 [180.16.10.386] 
21000,license(s) used by JITHIN THOMAS@TEST-36 [180.16.10.86] 
21000,license(s) used by Afzal@DEMO-10 [180.16.10.50] 
21000,license(s) used by STARHPC@DEMO-5 [180.16.10.15] 
21000,license(s) used by STARHPC@DEMO-5 [180.16.10.15] 
21000,license(s) used by STARHPC@HELP-001 [180.16.10.149] 
21000,license(s) used by STARHPC@HELP-001 [180.16.10.149] 
21000,license(s) used by STARHPC@HELP-001 [180.16.10.149] 
168000,of 168008 license(s) used:
```

This is my code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM set "string=A cat and dog had a [180.16.10.168]"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type output.txt') do (
 set line=%%a
 for /f "tokens=5" %%i in ("%line%") do set word2=%%i
 echo %word2%
 ECHO.
 echo !line!
)
REM start output1.txt
pause
```

I want to put new line after iterating same IP Addresses from the file,
can anyone help me with this,
am working on it by three days
thank you

Comment: batch script has to check for the IP address and it has to put a line after each section

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have tried. If you do not have any code, please edit your question to include the pseudocode you have written.

Comment: i have added code to my question please let me know the solution SomethingDark and Nidhi257

Comment: You are (almost) correctly extracting the IP address from the line (you should be using either `"!line!"` or `"%%a"` in the second `for` loop), but you aren't comparing it to anything. If you were adding in lines manually, what would you look at to know when to add a new line?

Comment: thanks for ur reply, i have added this condition after second for loop             if '%line%'=='%word2%' ECHO.    but it is adding empty line after one one line, my problem is to segregate all the same ip addresses in one one section @SomethingDark

Answer (score 0):

As SomethingDark already noted, you are very close. Use another method to extract the IP (because it's not token 5 in every line) and a variable to remember the last IP:

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (output.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%i in ("%%a") do (
   if "!oldIP!" neq "%%i" (
    if defined oldip echo/
    set "oldIP=%%i"
   )
  )
  echo %%a
 )
)>output1.txt
start output1.txt
pause
```

(Note: you can use the `for` variable (`%%a`) directly, no need for `!line!`.

Comment: I was just gonna nudge him in the right direction; I figured he'd get it eventually.

Comment: Thank you so much, it has got resolved, thank you for giving ur time

Comment: Just a little tickle to remove the initial newline when `oldip` is empty - otherwise, just as I had it (but I waffle too much :))